# Is there a difference between the strength of Telgram's (MTproto) forward secrecy and Signal's?

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, protocol-design, signal-protocol

If I understood correctly, the Signal protocol generates a new key after every message sent and forgets the previous one. Telegram, on the other hand, renews the key only after 100 messages or one week. Thus, is there a certain attack window (1 week / 100 messages) with Telegram's protocol?

Comment: Note that once we have this [The backdoor of Telegram on Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange and possibly other examples?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87532/18298), I don't trust on the Telegram. Only expecting that there is a hidden backdoor deeper somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think renew keys after a key generation is problematic because assume that key is already generated by the application. If somehow generate key pass through a function $H(x) = B(preImg(x))$. In simple language a function that somehow analysis key pattern and calculate $n$ pre-images of $x$.

Comment: How does one gets the preimage on [SHA-256](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end)

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8786/sha-256-probabilistic-partial-preimage-possible

Comment: I know that but how this really occurs in your answer. I want to see a robust answer, not something like I think...